# href reload page and continue to link

Tags: jquery, html

I am having issues with pagination in my catalog, when I change the page, the add to cart button does not load any value thus does not work. When I refresh the page it starts to work. As I have no idea where is the issue, I am looking for a quick fix.. I would like to implement the refresh in the page change buttons. Any idea how to implement into href to redirect and then refresh the new page? Or something that would refresh the page only once when visited?

```
<nav class="pagination">

  {block name='pagination_page_list'}
  <div>
    <ul class="page-list clearfix text-xs-center">
      {foreach from=$pagination.pages item="page"}

        <li {if $page.current} class="current" {/if}>
          {if $page.type === 'spacer'}
          <span class="spacer">&hellip;</span> {else}
          <a rel="{if $page.type === 'previous'}prev{elseif $page.type === 'next'}next{else}nofollow{/if}" href="{$page.url}" class="{if $page.type === 'previous'}previous {elseif $page.type === 'next'}next {/if}{['disabled' => !$page.clickable, 'js-search-link' => true]|classnames}">
                {if $page.type === 'previous'}
                  <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>{l s='Previous' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
                {elseif $page.type === 'next'}
                  {l s='Next' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                {else}
                  {$page.page}
                {/if}
              </a> 
          {/if}
        </li>

      {/foreach}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {/`block`}
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the templating system you are using?

Comment: If you're navigating to a new page, the code you're running on the previous page is necessarily no longer running. You'd have to write code on the "new page" to refresh it after loading, presumably only once. You're going to end up having to write a lot of code for a "quick fix". Better just to figure out why your code is not working as intended.